# Removing API secrets from RoboVM project

Tags: version-control, gradle, libgdx, api-key, robovm

In my Android project, I've used gradle build file to pull api keys from a local file outside of the source root and to automatically generate `BuildConfig` class and it's fields using a `buildConfigField`.

But I'm unable to do the same thing in my RoboVM project. I guess, the `BuildConfig` fields mentioned above are Android specific.

How can I remove API secrets from my RoboVM source code?